# How to install insync-beta-xfce, the Google Drive client for Xfce (thunarx-python missing)?

Tags: nautilus, python, xfce, thunar, insync

There are different types of **Insync** available for Ubuntu (see [here](https://www.insynchq.com/linux)).

I am trying to use it under **Xfce**, so the first choice would be to install the [Xfce version](http://s.insynchq.com/builds/insync-beta-xfce_0.9.41_i386.deb).

But I get this error:

[image]

How to solve this?

---

Installing the [generic version](http://s.insynchq.com/builds/insync-beta-ubuntu_0.9.41_i386.deb) works, but it also installs automatically Nautilus, which in Xfce starts taking over actions that otherwise should be reserved for Thunar. (I do not like to use Nautilus in Xfce - more [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/69485/47206).)

I guess that is why an Xfce version exists in the first place. But I cannot find how to install `thunarx-python`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Quantal version of the missing dependency `thunarx-python` is to be found [**here**](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8/quantal/main/base/thunarx-python).

(For other versions of Ubuntu look [**here**](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/webupd8?dist=quantal).)

After installing it, **Insync-Xfce** can be installed and works fine, with **Thunar** as file manager.