# How to disable nautilus from handling the desktop?

Tags: 11.10, unity, nautilus, gnome, themes

As it is the only way to activate transparent themes in Gnome-shell:

- How to disable Nautilus from handling the desktop?
- Can I make it handle the desktop again?
- What will happen to the unity and desktop icons?
- How to handle the desktop icons without nautilus?

Comment: use gnome-tweak-tool ... it's like the first option in the interface (to disable this specific thing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop` (or at least modify the `OnlyShowIn` line into it).

Then you should always run `nautilus` with the `--no-desktop` option (this could also require to modify some menu item or quicklist).

You can manage the desktop with nautilus again at any time launching nautilus without the option `--no-desktop`.

To manage the desktop in an alternative way you could look at some other file manager.

Comment: Works well.But i was shocked when opening Unity-DE that desktop icons still there, i was thinking that disable nautilus from handling the desktop will happen to all DE-s(i,e, nautilus still handling the desktop in unity and not handling the desktop in Gnome-shell and it is great)

Comment: This is a workaround. The solution is the one given by Jon Wood

Answer (score 22):

I found that running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false` instantly disabled the desktop icons.

Comment: This is a way better answer

Comment: This doesn't work on Pop_OS

Answer (score 5):

If you install the gnome tweak tool (which you'll want anyway) you can disable file manager handling the desktop (see Picture).  But as far as I know you will then have no desktop icons.  Most if not all DEs are structured such that the file manager handles desktop icons.

[image: d]

Comment: This worked wonderfully for me to prevent nautilus from loading the desktop backgrounds of gnome desktop manager (which were different than those I had in the des Xcfe desktop manager)