# How to setup Awesome WM with GNOME services on arbitrary Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, gnome, 13.04, gnome-panel, awesome

**tl;dr Is there a generic guide to set up GNOME *background services* to work with Awesome WM on any Ubuntu?**

The [official guide](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome#Ubuntu_11.10) doesn't seem to have been updated since Ubuntu 11.10. [Another guide](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1367-running-the-awesome-window-manager-within-gnome) is slightly more up to date, but after upgrading to 12.10:

1. GNOME panels on the top and bottom of the first monitor. They shouldn't be there.
2. Awesome WM background image.
3. Awesome panels on the second monitor.
4. Awesome controls work (<kbd>Mod4</kbd>+number to go to tag, etc.).

After upgrading to 13.04 today it's even worse:

1. GNOME panels on the top and bottom of the first monitor. Still shouldn't be there.
2. No panels on the second monitor.
3. Awesome WM background image.
4. `feh` error message when logging in even though it is installed. Sorry, can't copy it here since I can't reproduce (see below).
5. Windows are placed at X=0 and Y=something like -10 (the window title bars are about 90% offscreen). This means I can't access the menu in the top panel without closing all open applications (since they can't be moved by dragging with either <kbd>Mod4</kbd> or <kbd>Meta</kbd> held down).
6. Some GNOME keyboard shortcuts work (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), but not others (<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).
7. No Awesome keyboard or mouse controls work (<kbd>Mod4</kbd>+number, <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+mouse drag).

Points 3 and 4 only happened the first time after rebooting into 13.04; on the second login I get the Ubuntu background image and no `feh` error message.

The [command](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/568f716e70cdf676a01777cb7b23750af54ea7c8/.bash_history#L1526) I cobbled together to setup "Awesome GNOME" based on the guide (reformatted for readability):

```
sudo sh -c '
apt-get install awesome awesome-extra gnome-session-fallback notification-daemon && \
printf "%s\n" "[Desktop Entry]" "Version=1.0" "Type=Application" "Name=awesome" "TryExec=awesome" "Exec=awesome" | tee /usr/share/applications/awesome.desktop && \
printf "%s\n" "[Desktop Entry]" "Name=Gnome with Awesome" "Comment=Gnome with Awesome as window manager" "TryExec=gnome-session" "Exec=gnome-session --session=awesome" "Type=Application" | tee /usr/share/xsessions/gnome-awesome.desktop && \
printf "%s\n" "[GNOME Session]" "Name=Awesome" "RequiredComponents=gnome-panel;gnome-settings-daemon;" "RequiredProviders=windowmanager;notifications;" "DefaultProvider-windowmanager=awesome" "DefaultProvider-notifications=notification-daemon" | tee /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/awesome.session'
```

@RolandSommer's answer fixed most of the issues. In the meantime I worked around a crash by [commenting out all `awful.util.spawn`](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=705011) entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have gnome-panel as requirement in your session description, so you are actually requesting the panels to be there.

Besides the gnome-panel-requirements I use the exact same setup within Ubuntu 13.04 and it works perfect.

Change

```
RequiredComponents=gnome-panel;gnome-settings-daemon;
```

to

```
RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;
```

and you are set.

Comment: Fixes all the problems except the `feh` error messages, which I can totally live with.

Answer (score 0):

About feh error message:
Try to change theme.wallpaper_cmd in your theme.lua to { "" }. Gnome services will set wallpaper for you without any help (at least it works in 12.10)

Comment: Actually, i just found better solution to solve wallpaper problem: you need to disable nautilus desktop handling, so it will stop conflicting with feh on first startup
http://askubuntu.com/questions/84847/how-to-disable-nautilus-from-handling-the-desktop