# Out of the box into the terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, desktop-environments

I am wondering if there is a possibility to modify Ubuntu (ver. 14 although I'd update to 15 if it helps in the effort) in such a way that you boot into the terminal rather than the desktop.

I am not talking about removing the X-environment altogether. If one were to launch, say, Firefox, I'd like a window to appear on top of my terminal session and when all windows are closed, I'd like to return to said terminal.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run a terminal and window in the background and force it under every other window. This essentially replaces the desktop with your terminal window.

This is [something I've done before](https://askubuntu.com/a/366627/449) to help another user with a slightly different problem but it should apply just as well here. See that post for detail but all you need to do is run the following at login:

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,fullscreen,below; wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,skip_taskbar; bash"
```

You can edit your Gnome Terminal profile to make it look better too. And there are other terminal emulators out there which may suit this purpose better. Play around.